# Active Directory-LdapTemplate authenticates a user with password as empty field

Tags: ldap

The **authenticate()** method of **LdapTemplate** class lets authenticate a user of password field is empty. The code is like this:

`ldapTemplate.authenticate(ldapDto.getBaseDn(),
                    filter.encode(), "");`

Is there any way to enforce **authenticate()** method to let not enter to Active Directory if the password field is empty.

Your suggestions on this are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 possibilities with simple BIND in an LDAP-compliant server:

- null DN and null password - no authentication takes place (unsafe)
- DN and null password - no authentication takes place (unsafe)
- DN and password - authentication takes place and either succeeds or fails
- null DN and password - undefined by the LDAP standards, no authentication takes place (unsafe)

#### see also

- [LDAP: Authentication Best Practice](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/authentication-best-practices.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just want to know that if there is any way to implement the above method to not accept null password. The method is implemented in Spring-Ldap, that's why I added tags of Java, ldap-pring.